# I am trying to delete data from a table, using Laravel 4.2, and Elequent ORM, but it's not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete data from `Databetable`, using `Laravel 4.2` and `Elequent ORM`. But I'm unable to delete, here is my code:

```
//delete incoming calls against this number
\DB::table('incoming_call')
    ->where("contact_num",'=',$data['mobile'])
    ->delete();
//delete outgoing calls against this number
\DB::table('outgoing_call')
    ->where("contact_num",'=',$data['mobile'])
    ->delete(); `
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct usage, but this will delete only one row:

```
\DB::table('incoming_call')
          ->where("contact_num",'=',$data['mobile'])
          ->first();
          ->delete();


\DB::table('outgoing_call')
          ->where("contact_num",'=',$data['mobile'])
          ->first();
          ->delete();
```

If you want to delete multiple rows you can do something like this:

```
$coll = \DB::table('incoming_call')
              ->where("contact_num",'=',$data['mobile'])
              ->get();

\DB::table('incoming_call')->destroy($coll->keys());
```

Or just use simple `foreach`:

```
$coll = \DB::table('incoming_call')
          ->where("contact_num",'=',$data['mobile'])
          ->get();

foreach($coll as $one){
    $one->delete();
}
```